# Dynamically Adding a Column to a SQLAlchemy Table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a SQLAlchemy Table which is defined as:

```
class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
```

I am loading this table with data from a .csv file, and I may have columns which are not defined statically in the `Student` class. Let's say while loading the file, I find a new column that is not in the database, so I need to add it to the `Student` class.

So far I have tried this:

```
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from alembic.operations import Operations
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
    
op = Operations(MigrationContext.configure(db.engine.connect()))
    
return_col_list = []
for col_name in headers_list:
    # If the column is not already in the database, then create it.
    if (col_name not in COLUMN_HEADER_NAMES):
        lower_col_name = col_name.lower()
        try: 
            op.add_column('students', Column(lower_col_name, Text)) # Add the column
            Student.__table__.append_column(Column(lower_col_name, Text)) # Append the column to the table.
            return_col_list.append(col_name)
        except OperationalError:
            # The column already exists in the table.
            pass
    
return return_col_list
```

Then when I loop over each row of my .csv file, I do this to set the data to the attribute.

```
setattr(new_student, col, val)
```

However, when I set the data on a given `Student` object, the data is not reflected in the database. It appears there is no "link" between the column I made and the SQLite table itself. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps the change needs to be committed (presumably on the connection passed to `MigrationContext.configure`)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb That was a good, I did a test and it seems that didn't fix it :(